# Getting value of chosen html option in select element using onInput()

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, html-select, onchange

I want to trigger an event when an `option` in a `select` element is chosen. I have tried using `onChange()`, but it triggers the event when unfocusing from the selector. Using `onInput()` triggers the event at the right time, but then I can't access the value of the chosen option.

Here's my code using `onChange`.

```
onSelectChange(e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLSelectElement>) {
    this.setState({ selected: e.target.value  });
}

[...]

<select onChange={e => this.onSelectChange(e)}>
```

After changing to `onInput` (and `e:React.FormEvent<HTMLSelectElement>)` I get errors when writing `e.target.value`.

Answer (score 0):

onChange should work; see snippet for comparison/example:

```js
class Example extends React.Component {
  state={
    selected: '',
  }
  
  handleChange = e => {
    console.log("setting selected to " + e.target.value);
    this.setState({selected: e.target.value});
  }
  
  render() {
    return(
      <select value={this.state.selected} onChange={this.handleChange}>
        <option value="grapefruit">Grapefruit</option>
        <option value="lime">Lime</option>
        <option value="coconut">Coconut</option>
        <option value="mango">Mango</option>
      </select>
    )
  }
}


ReactDOM.render(<Example/>, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```